# Make a custom, signed EFI executable? (safeboot.dev)

Tags: linux, boot, security, uefi

I'm new Linux, I've used Xubuntu for the past three months so I only know the basics. Recently I came across [safeboot](https://safeboot.dev), which basically wraps up complex stuff to secure your system.

While reading the [installation page](https://safeboot.dev/install/), I came across this:

> A safer way to boot is to package the kernel, initrd and command line
> into a single EFI executable that is signed by the computer owner's
> key. This also reduces the attack surface by removing grub and the
> overly complicated config files, as well as speeds up the boot process
> a little bit.

How could I achieve this? Also googling for "how to package the kernel, initrd and command line into a single EFI executable" brings up EFIStub. Is this what I'm looking for? Are there any guides that would  work for me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a [Unified Kernel Image](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_kernel_image), which is a single executable consisting of a kernel, initrd and command line (and possibly some other things), which can then be signed for secure boot. The page I linked above is from Arch Wiki and contains complete instructions for creating a Unified Kernel Image and booting from it.